# Having Force Close with Targeted SDK

Tags: java, android, ringdroid

I have a problem with this source (Ringdroid: https://github.com/google/ringdroid ), last month I update my app wich targeted on android 23, but I just realise when I launch my app with android 23,24,25 it give me force close, so i change my targeted sdk to 22 but google play store says it can happen because previous version is targeted to 23. question is, it is a bug ? i need my project targeted on android 23 and still give me force close when i open using emulator or smartphone using marsmallow or nougat. how to fix this, sorry about my english

P.S.: when i change target sdk to 22 or above, it absouletly normal no force close happen.

```
03-12 02:46:05.141 15526-15526/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-12 02:46:05.205 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.220 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.250 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.262 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.273 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.283 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.294 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.303 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.312 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.329 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.339 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.ringdroid-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/x86/data@app@com.ringdroid-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-12 02:46:05.340 15526-15526/com.ringdroid W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ringdroid-1/lib/x86
03-12 02:46:05.341 15526-15526/com.ringdroid I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.ringdroid
03-12 02:51:21.753 15526-20262/com.ringdroid D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-12 02:51:21.766 15526-20260/com.ringdroid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                               Process: com.ringdroid, PID: 15526
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=15526, uid=10124 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
                                                                   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
                                                                   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
                                                                   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
                                                                   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
                                                                   at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:64)
                                                                   at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:56)
                                                                   at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
                                                                   at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
                                                                   at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
03-12 02:51:22.079 15526-20262/com.ringdroid I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-12 02:51:22.240 15526-20262/com.ringdroid E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaaa72470
03-12 02:56:22.073 15526-20260/com.ringdroid I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15526 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Your app `requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug at all. You need to add permission handling correctly into your code starting at API 23.

> If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, **and** your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, *and* it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running

[Android | Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)